# React Native: How to generate an APK?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to generate a test APK.

1. cmd: `create-react-native-app AwesomeProject`
2. cmd: `cd AwesomeProject`
3. cmd: `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
4. Created a folder(android/app), put the file my-release-key.keystore.
5. [In the documentation:](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

   > Edit the file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties and add the following
   >   (replace ***** with the correct keystore password, alias and key
   >   password)

   I do not have this file, how do I get it?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you are following is for app that created with `react-native-cli` and your app is created with `create-react-native-app`. To build and publish your app you either need to eject your app or follow [this documentation](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/README.md#sharing-and-deployment).

> ### Sharing and Deployment
>
> Create React Native App does a lot of work to make app setup and
>   development simple and straightforward, but it's very difficult to do
>   the same for deploying to Apple's App Store or Google's Play Store
>   without relying on a hosted service.